# How to run a function for each item in an array or write array objects individually on Mongoose

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongoose, axios

Hi everyone I'm trying to create an API for calculating revenue from a calculator service, all it essentially does is grab the values from the dB that the calculator needs and pass them through it and get the resulting values. I need to write the results back into the dB however for logging.

I'm having some problems however

I am trying to pass some objects from a Mongoose array to a JSON API URL service using axios get and I'm having trouble writing the resulting array to my Mongoose dB

Can anyone help me with what I'm missing?

See below

```js
/* Users : 
  _id : 5cac
  username: sample
  email: email@email.com
  orderHistory: [
  {xmr_hr: 9000}, 
  {xmr_hr: 2000}, 
  {xmr_hr: 3000}
  ],
  profitHistory:[
  {
    xmr_usd_gross:
  }
  ]
  
 */


var email = "email@email.com"
var id = "5cac"


function xmr(callback){
function getUsers(){ 
  var cursor = User.find({email: email}, function (err, users) {
}).cursor();
return cursor;
}



var cursor = getUsers();
cursor.on('data', function(name){



     const xmr_hr= name.orderHistory.map(element => element.xmr_hr);





var xmrLength = xmr_hr.length;
for (var i = 0; i < xmrLength; i++) {

console.log(xmr_hr[i]
// returns [9000,2000,3000]


        
// variables
var algo = "cn8"
var hr = xmr_hr

var wttURL = "wtt.com/json" + algo + hr[i]

axios.get(wttURL)
  .then((response) => {
    var btcGrossRevenue = response.data.coins.Monero.btc_revenue
    console.log(btcGrossRevenue)
    // runs through each value in array and returns revenue [0.06, 0.02, 0.03]

// below is my problem
var updateProfits = [{
    xmr_usd_gross : btcGrossRevenue,
        }]
      
      
        
      
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {upsert: false, "$addToSet": { 'profitHistory': updateProfits}},
      function(err, user) {
        if(err) { console.log(err) }
        else {
          console.log(user.length)
      };
    })
  })
}


// initial callback
for (var v = 1; v < 2; v++)
xmr(function(v){})


// cronJob and callback continuation
var xmrJob = new cron.CronJob('* 10 * * * *', function() {  
  console.log('Function executed!');
  
for (var v = 1; v < 2; v++) // amount of times to run function
xmr(function(v){})

}, null, true);

xmrJob.start
```

I know the problem is the fact that I'm trying to write an array to an object inside an array, but I'm not sure how to pass each object in the array individually.

I am thinking either there is a way to do it by just running the callback function individually for each object item in the array or find the ability to dissect the resulting array and write them sequentially.

I would like for my Collections to look like this once everything is written

```js
    /* Users : 
      _id : 5cac
      username: sample
      email: email@email.com
      orderHistory: [
      {xmr_hr: 9000}, 
      {xmr_hr: 2000}, 
      {xmr_hr: 3000}
      ],
      profitHistory:[
      {xmr_usd_gross: 0.06},
      {xmr_usd_gross: 0.03},
      {xmr_usd_gross: 0.02},
      ]
      
     */
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Map function.

```
const fn = (item) => {
  return item *10;
}
[1,2,3,4,5].map( fn );
```

with this simple example, the function *fn* is executed on each item in the map and returns a value.  If you assign it to something you can leverage that value resulting array.

I obviously seperated them out but you can easily do them inline as well.... or leverage the forEach function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```
[1,2,3,4,5].map( item => item * 10 );
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

```
[1,2,3,4,5].forEach( item => { 
  console.log( item * 10 ); 
});
```

Your arrays can be anything, objects, numbers whatever, and similarly... you can do anything in the functions.

Comment: Ok got it, I'm trying this now. Thank you very much

Comment: Do you know how I can join the resulting objects into one array? When I do console.log(btcGrossRevenue) it outputs all 4 results but 4 separate times (as it should since its 4 separate get requests) but in order for me to use that method you have, I need to combine them into one singular array, I researched and all I can find is how to concat two different variables, but I only have one variable for this instance

Comment: It sounds like you might want to look more into `async` and how to process that stuff. You can create an array of promises (returned from each execution), and then you can wait for them all to finish, and build out an array in the success call.